# Combining multiple SELECT functions where both have a WHERE

Tags: sql

I'm trying to normalize my data as it's entered from an excel sheet. The file I pull the data has a bunch of columns sibling1_name, sibling1_age, sibling1_affected etc for up to 4 siblings, 4 children, 4 relatives etc. I want to enter it all into a new table with name, age, affected and relationship. I've found a way to enter the first sibling correctly (see below) but I'm not sure how to add the others in. Any suggestions?

```
INSERT INTO Family
            (ID,
             Name,
             Age,
             Affected,
             Relationship)
SELECT ExcelPatients.id,
       ExcelPatients.sibling1_name     AS Name,
       ExcelPatients.sibling1_age      AS Age,
       ExcelPatients.sibling1_affected AS Affected,
       "Sibling"
FROM   ExcelPatients
WHERE  (( ( ExcelPatients.Sibling1_name ) IS NOT NULL ))
       AND ExcelPatients.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID  AND Name
                                    FROM   Family);
```

Comment: What kind of SQL is this?  And is "ExcelPatients" a table in that SQL database?

Comment: Is this your actual code? If so does it work? `SELECT DISTINCT ID and Name FROM Family` seems odd.

Comment: Yes, that's the table it's pulling from. All of the data is imported into that table from an Excel sheet and in that sheet, it's in those columsn I mentioned

Comment: It does work, it inserts it perfectly into one table.

Comment: I should mention that the ID is for one person who can have multiple family members.

Comment: When you use `NOT IN/IN` with a sub query, which can only have a single field. Also your subquery syntax looks wrong to me. How come this work? what is your DBMS?

Comment: I'm not sure why it works. Do you have any better ideas of code that works better than this does?

Comment: Which database system are you working with? Microsoft SQL-Server? MySQL? Oracle? PostGres? Please answer the question!

Comment: @leeer, and you don't know by now to not use code if you don't understand why it works? Likely it isn't working as you expect. This is not standard SQL and you need to specify the db is it even runs at all (It would not run on SQL server - I know I tried that construction and get an error message) for us to be sure we have code that will work for you. You should not ask a db question without specifying the datbase backend(s), it makes a difference in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO Family
            (ID,
             Name,
             Age,
             Affected,
             Relationship)

SELECoT ExcelPatients.id, ExcelPatients.sibling1_name AS Name, 
ExcelPatients.sibling1_age AS Age, 
ExcelPatients.sibling1_affected AS Affected, "Sibling"
FROM ExcelPatients
WHERE (((ExcelPatients.Sibling1_name) Is Not Null))
AND NOT EXISTS  (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Family where family.id =  ExcelPatients.id and Family.name =  ExcelPatients.sibling1_name)

UNION

SELECT ExcelPatients.id, ExcelPatients.sibling2_name AS Name, 
ExcelPatients.sibling2_age AS Age, 
ExcelPatients.sibling2_affected AS Affected, "Sibling"
FROM ExcelPatients
WHERE (((ExcelPatients.Sibling2_name) Is Not Null))
AND NOT EXISTS  (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Family where family.id =  ExcelPatients.id and Family.name =  ExcelPatients.sibling2_name)

UNION

SELECT ExcelPatients.id, ExcelPatients.sibling3_name AS Name, 
ExcelPatients.sibling3_age AS Age, 
ExcelPatients.sibling3_affected AS Affected, "Sibling"
FROM ExcelPatients
WHERE (((ExcelPatients.Sibling3_name) Is Not Null))
AND NOT EXISTS  (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Family where family.id =  ExcelPatients.id and Family.name =  ExcelPatients.sibling3_name)

UNION 

SELECT ExcelPatients.id, ExcelPatients.sibling4_name AS Name, 
ExcelPatients.sibling4_age AS Age, 
ExcelPatients.sibling4_affected AS Affected, "Sibling"
FROM ExcelPatients
WHERE (((ExcelPatients.Sibling4_name) Is Not Null))
AND NOT EXISTS  (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Family where family.id =  ExcelPatients.id and Family.name =  ExcelPatients.sibling4_name)
```

Without seeing the data I don't know if UNION ALL Or UNION is the right choice. If a name can only be in one of the 4 sibling columns then use UNION ALL, IF it can be repeated, then USE UNION. Since you are cleaning up data from another source UNION is probably thw safer but slower choice.  NOT EXISTS tends to be the fastest comparision in SQL Server which is why I chose it.

Comment: One more question, any way to have it input all of this data into an existing table?

Comment: Add the insert into stuff at the top